# angular ng-click ou javascript event click dentro da prop html do sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Eu estou tentando fazer uma implementação com SweetAlert2 onde crio alguns botões dentro da propriedade "html". Isto está dentro de uma função de clicar, que por sua vez está dentro de um `controller`.

Eu tentei adicionar em um `setTimeout()` e dentro do `$` `aplicar()` como código abaixo:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        swal({
            title: "Lançamento por Código",
            width: 400,
            html: "" +
            "   <div>" +
            "       <input type='button' id='btn0' name='btn0' value='0' />" +
            "   </div>" +
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#FFB200",
            cancelButtonColor: "#FFB200",
            colorHoverButton: "#5B2E90",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirmar",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            reverseButtons: true,
            input: "text"
        }).then(function () {

        });
    })
},0);
```

Para este botão que eu criei, eu tento criar um evento de clique, como o código abaixo:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $("input[name='btn0']").on("click", function () {
            $scope.valorLancProduto += "0";
            $('.swal2-input').val($scope.valorLancProduto);
        });
    })
},0);
```

Eu tentei colocar a mesma na função `init()` e uma função de clique. Meu problema surge agora, o evento `click` não está funcionando, não é chamado. Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, alterei na chamada do meu evento click, ficou da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn0", function () {
```

Obrigado.